# Upload an image from React toCloudinary using Express and File upload dependant

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, fetch, cloudinary

I am  new learning React and i would like some help with this feature. I want a user upload a picture and then when clicking "record" this will call my backend (with fetch and not Axios as I never use it yet) to send the URI of the picture to Cloudinary.

Then the url generated will be recorded in mongodb.

My route are almost ready because i created more or less the same feature with React Native but using the camera of the phone .

here is the code of the route to upload inside Cloudinary .

```
    router.post("/uploadPhoto", async function (req, res, next) {
  var myUser = await userModel.findOne({ _id: req.query.id });
  let imagePath = "./imgtmp/" + uniqid() + ".jpg";
  let resultCopy = await req.files.photo.mv(imagePath);
  let resultCloudinary = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imagePath);
  let cloudinaryUrl = JSON.stringify(resultCloudinary.secure_url);
  // console.log("tot", cloudinaryUrl);

  if (myUser && !resultCopy) {
    await userModel.updateOne(
      {
        _id: req.query.id,
      },
      {
        photo: resultCloudinary.secure_url,
      }
    );
    // console.log(myUser);

    res.json({
      result: true,
    });
  } else {
    res.json({ result: false, message: resultCopy });
  }

  fs.unlinkSync(imagePath);
});
```

Can you suggest how to upload the picture and use the same route if possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the current result that you get?

Comment: At the moment it's not working because the back can"'t read the URI .. I just would like to understand how can i get a link of the uploaded pictures to send to the back and send it to file upload dependencies for cloudinary